# Reverse Engineer Android Assets

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I am trying to reverse engineer an APK file.

I tried apk2jar to get classes and resource files. But I am not able to uncompress assets.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use apktool. It will reverse engineer all layouts, values, assets etc.

Apktool:
http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Comment: apktool sure extracts all the files from APK but it does not uncompress files inside assets. assets are compressed using aapt tool. I am trying to find out how to uncompress them.

Comment: The application which I was trying to work with had all the assets encrypted. I mistook the encrypted data with compressed data. Apktool certainly does what it promises.